# Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome Files drag tab

Tags: gnome, nautilus, window, 19.04

In Ubuntu 18.10, in the Files app (Nautilus) I could drag a tab outside to make it a separate window. This is the same behavior as in Firefox or Google Chrome.

In 19.04 this no longer works.

How can I enable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the screen in GNOME Files (Nautilus File Manager)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020183/how-to-split-the-screen-in-gnome-files-nautilus-file-manager)

Comment: @N0rbert, no. It not splits the view, but creates a separate window with the tab being dragged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that GNOME developers have [removed this option](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/NEWS#L106) instead of [fixing the underneath problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/137).

I see that it was working as expected in Nautilus inside 18.10:

[image: 18.10 tab dragging]

but now this option is missed.

I have reported [bug 1826586](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1826586) to launchpad.

If you hate such surprises as me do, then I can recommend you to switch to traditional desktop environments such as Xfce or MATE. And of course use LTS versions of Ubuntu with 5 years support.